# Weblogic Server Upgrade: EJB3 JPA KODO: No persistence unit named 'em' is available in scope

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, weblogic

I have been wrestling with this error for last few days. Please someone point out what is going wrong.

I have an EAR application in production on Weblogic Server 10.0 working just fine. When I deploy the same build EAR on Weblogic Server 10.3.4, I get an error:

> No persistence unit named 'em' is available in scope /projectEARName. Available persistence units: []

The application is an exploded EAR with exploded JAR and WAR. The JAR uses JPA (Kodo framework, which is the JPA RI in WebLogic) and EJB3. WAR uses JSF Framework.

Project Final Build Folder Structure (Build using ANT; All Exploded; Which get deployed in WLS)

- EAR

  - JAR

    - Project's Classes
    - META-INF

      - persistence.xml
      - ejb-jar.xml
      - weblogic-ejb-jar.xml
  - war

    - Project's UI Files
    - WEB-INF

      - lib
      - classes
  - META-INF

    - weblogic-application.xml
    - application.xml

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>kodo.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
<jta-data-source>SMDS</jta-data-source>
<class>com.aaa.bbbb.domainobjects.cccc</class>
<class>com.aaa.bbbb.domainobjects.dddd</class>
<class>com.aaa.bbbb.domainobjects.eeee</class>
<properties>
    <property name="kodo.jdbc.SQLFactory" value="BatchLimit=-1, SupportsUnion=true"/>
    <property name="kodo.DataCache" value="true(CacheSize=5000, SoftReferenceSize=0)"/>
    <property name="kodo.RemoteCommitProvider" value="sjvm"/>
    <property name="kodo.Log" value="DefaultLevel=INFO, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
</properties> 
</persistence-unit>
```

EJB Facade Class (which uses EntityManager)

```
@Stateless(name="XYZFacade", mappedName="XYZFacade")
public class XYZFacadeBean implements XYZFacade {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

I think the issue might be due to the change in JARs in modules folder in Weblogic installation folder. Any ideas, anyone ?

Comment: Have you tried something like `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU")`?

Comment: Yes, the error changes to: No persistence unit named 'PU' is available in scope /projectEARName. Available persistence units: []